# Differentiate the compound words

Tags: grammar

In accounting, we use compound words like "electricity expense", "utility expense", "salary expense", etc. These all belong to one category of operating expenses. I also have compound words like "deferred expenses" and "prepaid expenses" which belong to the balance sheet.

Is there a fundamental difference between phrases like "salary expense" and "prepaid expense"? Is the below statement correct?

> "Salary expense" is a compound noun where "salary" is a noun and "expense" is a noun, and "prepaid expense" is a compound noun where "prepaid" is adjective and "expense" is a noun.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with writing.

Comment: How can there be a difference between *salary expense* and *prepaid expense* when neither appears in a dictionary as a discrete noun? However one of them is used, so is the other. Something like *hot dog* would be different, because it has enough common use to have become a noun in its own right. The presence of an open, hyphenated, or closed compound is simply an indicator of its common use in normal English. All of the phrases used in the question might appear as terminology in economic or accounting texts. If so, then they still have that in common.

Comment: Compound nouns often *derive* from different word parts, but they have become so common as to no longer be properly analyzable in that sense when used as a whole. This is no different than idioms, whose meanings often differ from, or don't make sense according to, the individual words they're made from. Also, an attributive noun and an adjective both serve the same functional grammatical role.

Comment: With [Adj + Noun] and [Noun + Noun] couplets where the first word modifies the headword, there is agradation of cohesiveness: Free Association ... Loose Collocation ... Strong Collocation ... Compound Noun. (There may be hyphenation or coalescence at the final transition.) A compound noun is a single unit of meaning (lexeme) no matter how it is spelled (ink well ... ink-well ... inkwell).  Where the premodifier is an adjective, there is generally a lesser cohesiveness (though of course not always). Peanut butter vs rancid butter. Nowadays, compounds tend to be given in the larger ...

Comment: dictionaries, though domain-specific terms are more likely to be found in dedicated glossaries or dictionaries. // As for the _semantic types_ of modifiers associated with headnouns, there's a related post somewhere. With _peanut butter_, obviously the relation is 'H is made of P'; with _football manager_, 'H is associated with (/ employed within) P'. With _walking stick_, 'H is facilitated by P'. With _blackbird_, 'H is of the colour P' (though lexicalisation has occurred, so _black bird_ is far wider in scope than _blackbird_).